# NetSuite Transaction Saved Search by Period - KPI Scorecard

Tags: search, transactions, formula, kpi

I am trying to create a transaction saved search to apply to a custom KPI Scorecard.

The transaction saved search requires the 'Available Filters' Period filter since the custom KPI Scorecard has the 'By Period' checkbox ticked.

I would like to count the number of customers, by period, that only have one sales invoice on their account.

For example, if customer A, B and C each only had one sales invoice dating back to May 2023, then I would like to show count of 3 in May 2023.

If customer D only had one sales invoice dating back to June 2023, then the scorecard should then show: May 2023 = 3, June 2023 = 1

Thanks,
Ryan

Saved Search current settings are:

- Type = Transaction
- Criteria Standard = Type = Invoice
- Criteria Summary = Count Internal ID is 1
- Results = Period Maximum
- Results = Internal ID Count
- Results = Customer : Name Group